# Issue while generating Signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

Facing **AAPT2 error: check logs for details** issue while generating Signed APK. Normally when taking build it give successful apk, while generating Signed APk it blocks.

[image: Here is the gradle file]

And the error file is placed below for further information

[image: Please kindly guide me further. Thanks]

Comment: what does the error is the 'Messages' view say?

Comment: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: Above is the error message i am getting in message view @Boe-Dev

Comment: post your error log from message view. You can open message view from through `a/b` button, just below the green hammer in left side buttons panel in Build section.

Comment: Click the icon directly under the green hammer icon to see the full build log. Post that here so we can see the error.

Comment: do you use androidx?

Comment: No i am not using

Answer (score 0):

Since the logs are not posted. I believe one of the reasons for the build failure is due to some PNG files are corrupted and were not parsed. Sometimes the images have an extension but are not real PNG.

You can check if the images in your project are real PNGs with the below command :

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" | xargs -L 1 -I{} file  -I {} | grep -v 'image/png; charset=binary$'
```

After getting the list I used [this](https://www.online-convert.com/) site to convert them to PNG. I was then able to generate a signed apk.